# mod_authnz_ldap OR multiple LDAP groups

Tags: ldap

I am working with Apache 2.4 and the module mod_authnz_ldap to grant or authorize to users in a group to certain pages. 
This is my current configuration. This is working fine:

```
    AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://myldapserver.com:389/dc=example, dc=com?uid"
    AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative on
    AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off

    <RequireAll>

       Require ldap-group cn=mygroup,ou=group,dc=example,dc=com

    </RequireAll>
```

My question is:

It is possible to authorize to more than one group? This means to make an OR of the groups and authorize to any of them.

I was trying to do it inserting a **SatisfyAny** directive inside the **RequireAll** and I did not manage to make it work.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Require ldap-filter](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html) can be used with any valid LDAP filter. So something like:

```
Require ldap-filter (&(memberOf='cn=mygroup,ou=group,dc=example,dc=com')(cn=mygroup33,ou=group,dc=example,dc=com))
```

Should work. Of course assuming that memberOf is present in your LDAP implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Why not replace RequireAll directive with a RequireAny?

```
<RequireAny>
  Require ldap-group A
  Require ldap-group B
  Require ldap-group C
</RequireAny>
```